# Using the pluralize method in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this seems silly, but I would like to call some of Rails' Text Helpers in a rake task I am setting up. (Thinks like the pluralize and cycle method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html)

How would you go about making these available in a rake task, or is it not easily possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's rather messy to extend ActionView::Helpers in your rake task - that basically includes *all* helper methods in your Rake task.

`ActionController::Base.helpers.pluralize(5, 'dog')`

If you don't have a count and you just want to pluralize a word:

`ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize('dog')`

Answer (score 3):

Adding ActiveSupport and ActionPack as dependencies could be heavy handed to simply have the convenience of a text helper -- unless your Rakefile is already loading Rails -- but here's an example Rakefile:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'activesupport'
require 'actionpack'
require 'action_view/helpers'

extend ActionView::Helpers

task :plural do
  puts "I have #{pluralize(5, "dog")}"
  puts "You have #{pluralize(1, "dog")}"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

## In Rails 3:

```
require 'active_support/inflections'
require 'action_view/helpers'
extend ActionView::Helpers

task :plural do
  puts "I have #{pluralize(5, "dog")}"
  puts "You have #{pluralize(1, "dog")}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the pluralized version of the string, you can just call `pluralize` on it directly without loading anything extra in your rake task:

```
"dog".pluralize
```

You could then just replace the pluralize helper with something like this:

```
word = "dog"
if count == 1
  plural = "1 #{word}"
else
  plural = "#{count} #{word}".pluralize
end
puts plural
```